# SSAS Tabular data refresh

Tags: data-processing, ssas-tabular

I am developing SSAS Tabular project for Power BI, as part of requirement I need to automate the below process
 1. Every week I have to delete last two weeks of data in SSAS Table
2. Update last two weeks of data.

Thanks in advance
Please advice

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to create an SSIS Package to delete the last two weeks of data and then process the cube.

1. Your SSIS Package to delete the last 2 weeks of data.
2. Schedule to process your SSAS cube.

Answer (score 1):

SSAS Tabular, Power Pivot, Power BI don't provide facilities to allow a partial refresh, sliding window or any other type of refresh other than full data refresh (Power BI premium does but assuming you're not using that).

You need to control the data getting into the data model by controlling the data in the source tables underlying the model.

This is commonly done using SSIS, TSQL and/or stored procedures.